# How Can we convert comma separated CSV either "," or ";" separated CSV file to Excel file using VBA in MS Access?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

In Ms Access, I have a CSV file wherein data is like this

```
id,name,roll
101,jack,32
102,jill,33
```

using VBA, I want to convert the above file into an excel file (.xls or .xlsx) wherein data will get stored in separate columns:

```
|id | name| roll|
|101| jack| 32  |
|102| jill| 33  |
```

I know how to do it using ms access built-in feature ,but want to do it programmatically using VBA code.

Comment: Create an excel object, open the file and save as `.xlsx` perhaps?

Comment: Have you tried just opening the CSV file in Excel? If that fails, maybe change the delimiter from a semi-colon to a comma.

Comment: Excel doesn't recognize semi-colon separator. Access can import/link to that text file with the semi-colon set as the separator character. Then export table to Excel. Technically, that is not a CSV file. Does that file have .txt extension?

Comment: This is a multi-part process: 1) import/link and 2) export to Excel. Can be accomplished manually with Access ribbon tools. If you want to automate, attempt code and when you have some with specific issue post question.  Each is common topic and numerous VBA examples.

Comment: Which is the separator,  comma or semicolon?  In the title, you indicate that it's a semicolon.  In the body of the question,  you show a comma between fields.

Comment: If it's a semicolon separator,  your best bet is to set up a table link to an external text file.  During part of that setup, you will have a dialog with either the Text Import Wizard or the Text Link Wizard.  Either wizard will let you set the delimiter as tab, comma, or semicolon.  It will also let you specify that the first row (record) contains the field names.  Once this is complete, you will be able to use this link as a data source either interactively or within VBA.